# Using the URLconf defined in wiki.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django, url, server

this question was asked before but i cant find the solution to this.

When i run server i get this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoElK.png)

here is my code:
** helo\urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.index, name='index')
    ]
```

**helo\views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse


    def index(request):
      return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

** wiki\urls.py:**

```
 from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include,path


    urlpatterns = [
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      path('helo/', include("helo.urls")),
    ]
```

and i did put 'helo' in INSTALLED_APPS

Why do i get this error?

Comment: Did you reboot the dev server after you made these changes?

Comment: I did reboot the dev srv.